# Can prometheus read consul node meta?

Tags: consul, prometheus

According to https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_node_meta 
I can associate with a consul node any metadata key/value pair.

Can prometheus read this metadata ?
I understand that only the following meta labels are available for prometheus:

- __meta_consul_address: the address of the target
- __meta_consul_node: the node name defined for the target
- __meta_consul_tags: the list of tags of the target joined by the tag separator
- __meta_consul_service: the name of the service the target belongs to
- __meta_consul_service_address: the service address of the target
- __meta_consul_service_port: the service port of the target
- __meta_consul_service_id: the service ID of the target
- __meta_consul_dc: the datacenter name for the target

But I would like to be absolutely sure that I miss nothing or there is no a trick to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This was introduced into [Prometheus 1.8](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180--2017-10-06)

You can now simply reference `__meta_consul_metadata_$KEYNAME`

The following shows a prometheus label rewrite which filters the nodes 'location' metadata to a `ldn` fact which we've added to Consul agents running in London.

`- source_labels: [__meta_consul_metadata_location]
    separator: ;
    regex: ldn
    replacement: $1
    action: keep`

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported as the feature was only released a month ago, but feel free to send a pull request.